# Change DisplayName during run time (Desktop Client)

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

The Attribute DisplayName can be changed during design time on various objects such as entities, properties and so on.
I would like to change the DisplayName at run time in the Desktop Client.
For some objects it is easy, such as screens or entities: They provide explicitly a property.

For entity properties it is a little bit different.
I only can change the DisplayName if the programmer has explicitly added a Display Name during design time.

This code here works perfectly:

```
IServiceProxy sproxy = VsExportProviderService.GetExportedValue<IServiceProxy>();
IModuleDefinition module = sproxy.ModelService.Modules.Where(m => m.Id == "LightSwitchApplication.Localization.DesktopClient:!module").SingleOrDefault();
IEnumerable<IGlobalItem> items = module.GlobalItems;
var entities = items.OfType<EntityType>().Where(e => e.Name == "CoreApplication");
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    DisplayName dn;

    foreach (var property in entity.Properties)
    {
        dn = property.Attributes.OfType<DisplayName>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (dn != null)
        {
            dn.value = Helper.CreateNewValue();
        }

    }
}
```

But if dn is null how can I add a new DisplayName without running into an exception at a later stage, e.g. during a save action?

Thanks for your help.

Hans

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix for your specific problem, but a possible workaround.

If you were to create a local variable (say myLabelString) in your screen, you should be able to drag it into the appropriate location in the screen control tree, then dataBind() the value of the attribute value you're after to the HTML element in run-time using the PostRender() event.  You can format this element arbitrarily using $(element).replaceWith("<..>" + contentItem.stringValue + "") and then simply turn off the caption for the field concerned.

e.g.  This would detect changes in your variable value and update the label control on screen, rendering it as an H3 element.

```
myapp.MyScreen.myLabelString_postRender() = function (element, contentItem) {
    contentItem.dataBind ("stringValue", function (newValue) {
        contentItem.stringValue = newValue.ToString();
    });
    $(element).replaceWith("<h3>" + contentItem.stringValue + "</h3>");
}
```

For more on data binding, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2012/12/06/custom-controls-and-data-binding-in-the-lightswitch-html-client-joe-binder.aspx.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Ozziemedes
Unfortunately your answer does not help me now, because I am working with the desktop client. I certainly will use your code while working with the html client.

Best Regards,

Comment: Ah - in the desktop client this is much easier.  Same approach, but the data binding is pretty much a straight assignment rather than having to bubble the event through all the JavaScript layers.